# Aurelia UI virtualization with flex box divs (five columns)

Tags: javascript, css, aurelia, ui-virtualization

I have an Aurelia app where I want to have an infinite scroll in one part of a dashboard application. So, my scrolling area is only on one part of the screen. I have it scrolling but the scroll is jerky every three or four lines and I am trying to figure out how to tune the ui virtualization plugin or my use of it to not have jerky scrolling.

I have tried making the container larger and smaller. I have not tried making it a table. I am using flex-box for the items in the infinite scroll, and I have five items, instead of one like the demo application, across, in columns, inside the repeatable div like this:

```
            <div class="" style="overflow: scroll;
                                 height: 1000px">
                <div class=" " virtual-repeat.for="row of rows" 
                                             style="display: -webkit-flex;
                                                    display: flex;
                                                    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
                                                    flex-direction: row;
                                                    height:300px;">
                    <div class="card" style="height:300px;">
                        <img src.bind="row.item1.image" ref="image" />
                        <div class="card-section">
                            <h3>First column</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="height:300px;">
                        <img src.bind="row.item2.image" ref="image" />
                        <div class="card-section">
                            <h3>second column</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="height:300px;">
                        <img src.bind="row.item3.image" ref="image" />
                        <div class="card-section">
                           <h3>third column</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="height:300px;">
                        <img src.bind="row.item4.image" ref="image" />
                        <div class="card-section">
                            <p>4th column</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="height:300px;">
                        <img src.bind="row.item5.image" ref="image" />
                        <div class="card-section">
                            <p>5th column</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Ditto.  Saw same problem last week.

Comment: Further futzing has not helped me figure this out.

Comment: Can you provide sample gist or viewmodel(JS) file related this page